# Unordered List, List Item, JS / HTML Question

Tags: javascript, html

I found a few posts referencing something similar but I could not get it working..

Simply I am trying to create a List as shown below.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com">foo</a> </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

However when generating it through JS I get one of the following.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
        foo
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
        bar
    </li>
</ul>
```

OR

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        foo
        <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        bar
        <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the JS code provided.

```
function addListItem(id, str, url) {

var list = document.getElementById(id);

var el = document.createElement("LI");

var text = document.createTextNode(str);

if (url !== "") {

    var a = document.createElement("A");

    a.setAttribute("href", url);

    el.appendChild(text);

    el.appendChild(a);

} else {

    el.appendChild(text);

}

list.appendChild(el);

}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Issue

Take a look at these two lines:

```
el.appendChild(text);
el.appendChild(a);
```

First, you append the text...

```
<li>
    foo
</li>
```

Then you append the `<a>`...

```
<li>
    foo
    <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
</li>
```

---

### The Solution

What you need to do instead, is *append your  text to your `<a>` first*:

```
a.appendChild(text);
```

```
<a href="https://google.com">foo</a>
```

Then append *that* to your `<li>`:

```
el.appendChild(a);
```

```
<li><a href="https://google.com">foo</a></li>
```

**Corrected version:**

```js
function addListItem(id, str, url) {
  var list = document.getElementById(id);
  var el = document.createElement("LI");
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  
  if (url !== "") {
    var a = document.createElement("A");
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.appendChild(text);
    el.appendChild(a);
  } else {
    el.appendChild(text);
  }

  list.appendChild(el);
}

addListItem("list", "foo", "https//google.com");
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'foo.com');
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('bar'));
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The text is a child of the a tag, not the li tag.

a.appendChild(text);